# Django: how to update a ManyToManyField in a custom Django management task?

Tags: python, django, django-orm, manytomanyfield

In Django I have a model where one of the fields (`tags`) is a `ManyToManyField`:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

   id = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='')
   author = models.CharField(max_length=300)
   copy = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
   tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

I have a custom management task below where I'm getting all of the instances of the `MyModel` table on a server and using that to replace the instances of the `MyModel` table on my local server. (I'm running this custom management task from my local)

Here's what I'm trying so far.

However I'm getting this error: **CommandError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use tags.set() instead.**

How can I update the `tags` field that's a ManyToMany field?

```
from bytes.models import MyModel

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        try:
            // get queryset of MyModel instances from server
            queryset = MyModel.objects.using('theserver').all()

            // loop through that queryset and create a list of dictionaries
            mymodel_list = [
                {
                    'id': mymodel['id'],
                    'title': mymodel['title'],
                    'author': mymodel['author'],
                    'copy': mymodel['copy'],
                    'tags': mymodel['tags']
                } 
                for mymodel in queryset
            ]

            //delete all objects in the local MyModel table
            MyModel.objects.all().delete() 

            //replace with MyModel instances from server
            new_mymodel = [
                MyModel(
                    id=mymodel['id'],
                    title=mymodel['title'],
                    author=mymodel['author'],
                    copy=mymodel['copy'],
                    tags=mymodel['tags'] <--- causing error
                )
                for mymodel in mymodel_list
            ]

            MyModel.objects.bulk_create(new_mymodel)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ManyToMany` fields are working differently from any other field. You cannot simply copy it's values, especially from strings. You can try add objects in a loop just after after creating `MyModel`:

```
    //replace with MyModel instances from server
    new_mymodels = []
    for mymodel in mymodel_list:
        new_mymodel = MyModel(
                id=mymodel['id'],
                title=mymodel['title'],
                author=mymodel['author'],
                copy=mymodel['copy']
            )

        for tag in mymodel['tags']:
            new_mymodel.tags.add(tag)

        new_mymodels.append(new_mymodel)

    MyModel.objects.bulk_create(new_mymodel)
```

It is possible, that you will have to firstfully find the `Tag` object before `.add()` method. It depends on values in `mymodel['tags']`.